# Вылетает приложение.Intent-android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Почему вылетает приложение? Активность не успевает открыться.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.dz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1,btn2;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     Main2Activity.class);
                //кладём в интент значения с EditText с ключём "second"
                intent.putExtra("second",getTextFromEdit());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("third", getTextFromEdit());

                    //запускаем активити для получения с неё результата
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                }
                });

        }
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent         data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                editText.setText("");
                editText.setText(data.getStringExtra("result"));
                }
        }

        void initView(){
                btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
                btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

            editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        }
        String getTextFromEdit(){
            return editText.getEditableText().toString();
            }

}
```

Comment: Добавьте стектрейс // Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что вы получаете NullPointerException на 3 строке `onCreate`.

Comment: Вы забыли вызвать `initView()` в `onCreate()`

Comment: @woesss Спасибо!